# Avoid non-specified attributes on model creation (Django + MongoDB)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create an object in Python but, since I'm using Django, I don't want to save those attributes with None or null value.
When I create an object passing a couple of arguments, those attributes passed are assigned correctly; but the rest, which I wish were not created, are assigned the value "None"

models.py:

```py
from djongo import models

class MyClass(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key = True)
    attr1 = models.TextField()
    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    attr3 = models.IntegerField()
    attr4 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    a = MyClass( _id = 'TestID', attr1 = 'Xxxx' )
    for key in a:
        print(str(key) + " = " + str(a[key]))
    a.save()
```

What I get from the print loop is:

```py
_id = TestID
attr1 = Xxxx
attr2 = None
attr3 = None
attr4 = None
```

Which means I am saving an object full of empty data.

I would like to save a MyClass object with just the specified attributes in order to save space in memory.

EDIT:

I changed the code and only used djongo. Before I was using mongoengine's Document structure, but not anymore.

Also, I have checked what's written in the MongoDB database and it saves this:

```py
    {
        "_id" : "TestAptm_2",    #Type String
        "access" : "",           #Type String
        "address" : "",          #Type String
        "capacity" : null,       #Type null
        "city" : ""              #Type String
    }
```

Those empty and null values is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As django models are the bridge between your complex python objects and your database, which makes up the django ORM system and is an essential part of your database, you simply must not design your fields dynamically. This is same as having a database table with different number of columns per row, which is impossible. Instead of doing that, you can create separate models for each type of object of your and store them in your database that way.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "you simply must not design your fields dynamically", I'm sorry. MongoDB is able to store objects as a JSON with the fields specified and not save empty data, that's what's great about it.

Comment: Of course I was not talking about no sql dbs. Dynamic fields are what no sql dbs meant for thats no brainer. What Im mentioning is for relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the attributes of the python object which doesn't necessarily reflects what got saved in the database.

To check the the shape of the raw object in the database, you can use `as_pymongo()` method.

Mongoengine is actually behaving as you want, see below:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    _id = StringField(max_length=20, primary_key = True)
    atr1 = StringField()
    atr2 = StringField(max_length=300)
    atr5 = StringField(max_length=50)
    atr6 = IntField()

MyClass(_id='whatever', atr1='garbage').save()

print(MyClass.objects.as_pymongo())
# [{u'atr1': u'garbage', u'_id': u'whatever'}]
```

Comment: I did the test and it is actually saving the whole thing, with the empty values and stuff. Any other idea about what might be happening?

Comment: You observe that with my code snippet? Which mongoengine version are you using?

Comment: I had to remove mongoengine from the code because it has compatibility problems with the latest Django version. So in the end I am using djongo. And instead of Documents, djongo works with its own models (which I think are Django's models with some extensions)

Comment: But yes, with the actual code, the snippet you proposed still saves all the unnecessary fields. I cannot use as_pymongo(), but I looked it up on the DB directly. I very much appreciate your help, though, thank you

Comment: My comment only applies to mongoengine, djongo is a totally different library so it doesn’t work the same way internally